# Do I need to unlink before deleting? Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

This should be a fairly simple question and I might be stupid/blind to the exact spot in the docs where my question will be answered but:

```
Blog has many tags, tags belong to blog
post has many tags, tags belong to post
```

If I do:  `TagModel::where('id', $id)->first()->delete();` will that handle the relationships? as in if I do: `BlogsModel::where('id', $blogId)->tags` or even look through posts, I wont see that relationship for the deleted tag, or do I need to first unlink from blogs and posts **AND THEN** delete???

I assume laravel isn't going to me me unlink first ??

Comment: you could test this for your self quite easily

Comment: Or you could just answer the question quite easily.

Comment: know the parable about giving a man a fish?

Comment: Again, its super simple to say look here in the docs, or heres the answer, also look here. Enough "parables" more answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel relationship is used for calling the relation members, it's not used for deleting, if you want to automatically delete the relation table there is 2 ways:

1. you need to added relation on database that has on delete function

   ```
   $table->foreign('blog_id')->references('id')->on('blog')->onDelete('cascade');
   $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('blog')->onDelete('cascade');
   ```

or

2. You can added on delete function to your model

   You need added this funtion to your tag model :

   ```
   // Adding relation from tags to post
   public function post()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo( PostModel::class, 'post_id' );
   }

   // Adding relation from tags to blog
   public function blog()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo( BlogModel::class, 'blog_id' );
   }

   // Deleting relation table blog and post
   protected static function boot() {
       parent::boot();

       static::deleting( function( $tag ) {
           $tag->blog()->delete();
           $tag->post()->delete();
       });
   }
   ```

So when you run this function :

```
TagModel::where('id', $id)->first()->delete();
```

The related blog and post are automatically deleted.

If you want to delete tag and the related blog and post not deleted, just don't make any relationship between them at database.

Answer (score 0):

The key is the model event `deleting`:

```
/**
 * Events
 */
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($model) {
        foreach($model->tags as $tag) {
            $tag->delete();
        }      
    }
}
```

This code can live within the model itself or you can extract it to a model observer.